# XML parsing issue jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

Here is my issue I have this jquery xml parsing issue. The funny thing is everything works accept the id keeps coming up as undefined. My question is what is causing the ID to be undefined? Which is not good! So here is my script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         $.get('http://www.mytasteofitaly.com/menu/menu-1a.xml', function(data){
                     $(data).find('main').each(function(){
                    var $main = $(this);
                    var id = $main.attr('id');

            var html = '<div class="mainmen" id="main_' + id + '">';
            $('#menuitem').append($(html));
    });
        $(data).find('menu').each(function(){
        var $menu = $(this);
        var head = $menu.find('menuhead').text();

        var html = '<table class="menus"><th><h1>' + head + '</h1></th>';

        $('.mainmen').append($(html));
    });
        $(data).find('menuitem').each(function(){

            var $menuitem = $(this);
            var name = $menuitem.find('menuname').text();
            var desc = $menuitem.find('menudesc').text();
            var price = $menuitem.find('price').text();
            var desprice = $menuitem.find('price2des').text();
            var price2 = $menuitem.find('price2').text();


            var html = '<tr class="menu_item">';
            html += '<td class="h-menu">' + name + '</td>';
            html += '<td class="d-menu">' + desc + '</td>';
            html += '<td class="price">' + price + '</td>';
            html += '<td class="desprice">' + desprice + '</td>';
            html += '<td class="price2">' + price2 + '</td>' + '</tr>';

            $('.menus').append($(html));   
    });
});
});
```

Here is my XML

```
<main>
    <menu id="appet">
        <menuhead>
        Appetizers
        </menuhead>
        <menuitem>
            <menuname>
            Cheese Stick
            </menuname>
              <menudesc>
             (6 Sticks)
            </menudesc>
            <price>
            $7
            </price>
            <price2des>
            </price2des>
            <price2>
            </price2>
        </menuitem>
        <menuitem>
        <menuname>
        Fried Mushrooms
        </menuname>
        <menudesc>
        </menudesc>
        <price>
        $7
        </price>
        <price2des>
        </price2des>
        <price2>
        </price2>
    </menuitem>
    <menuitem>
        <menuname>
        Fried Calamari
        </menuname>
        <menudesc>
        </menudesc>
        <price>
        $9
        </price>
        <price2des>
        </price2des>
        <price2>
        </price2>
    </menuitem>
    <menuitem>
        <menuname>
        Bruchetta
        </menuname>
        <menudesc>
        </menudesc>
        <price>
        $10
        </price>
        <price2des>
        </price2des>
        <price2>
        </price2>
    </menuitem>
    <menuitem>
        <menuname>
        Shrimp Bruchetta
        </menuname>
        <menudesc>
        </menudesc>
        <price>
        $10
        </price>
        <price2des>
        </price2des>
        <price2>
        </price2>
    </menuitem>
    <menuitem>
        <menuname>
        Garlic Bread
        </menuname>
        <menudesc>
        </menudesc>
        <price>
        $3
        </price>
        <price2des>
        With Cheese
        </price2des>
        <price2>
        $4
        </price2>
    </menuitem>

    <menuitem>
        <menuname>
        Soups
        </menuname>
        <menudesc>
        (Minestrone or Pasta Fagioli) Cup
        </menudesc>
        <price>
        $4
        </price>
        <price2des>
        Bowl
        </price2des>
        <price2>
        $6
        </price2>
    </menuitem>

    <menuitem>
        <menuname>
        Zupa de Mussels
        </menuname>
        <menudesc>
        </menudesc>
        <price>
        $7
        </price>
        <price2des>
        </price2des>
        <price2>
        </price2>
    </menuitem>

    <menuitem>
        <menuname>
        Side Meatballs or Sausage or Alfredo Sauce
        </menuname>
        <menudesc>
        </menudesc>
        <price>
        $4
        </price>
        <price2des>
        </price2des>
        <price2>
        </price2>
    </menuitem>
</menu>
 </main>
```

And here is my HTML

```
<div id="Menuitem">
</div>
```

Here is a jsfiddle I setup http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/MEgdw/

Much appreciated.

Comment: that fiddle is blocked by the Same Origin Policy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`main` tags don't have an ID....`menu` tags do

**EDIT: Problem with xml parsing loops**

`menuitems` are nested in `menu` is nested in `main`

This means that within the `each` of the ancestor you need to call the each of the children. Nested data means nested loops

```
$(data).find('main').each(function() {

    var $main = $(this);

    $main.find('menu').each(function() {

        var $menu = $(this);

        $menu.find('menuitem').each(function() {

        });
    });
})​;​
```

Comment: One last question, my script is taking and applying my entire XML database to each div id. What am I doing wrong with my XML jquery call?

Comment: OK... gave you an edit in question that should mak lighbulbs go off

Comment: well I took your advice and I had some issues. Can you take a look at my new script.  http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/uc7F7/  Its no longer loading the xml... Uggg im such a noob!

Comment: not sure what to look for...structurally seems OK. If it's not working post a link to a really simple live page of it that pulls in the xml

Comment: This is the error i get does that help? Unexpected end of input

Comment: no..that's a wierd one... I would need to see it in browser console, and know when that error occurs

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18743/discussion-between-cam-and-charlietfl)